# 'RatingControlChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

net using VB. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2011/05/ajax-rating-control-sample-with.html) for doing my ratings controller

But I am getting the following error

```
Error   1   'RatingControlChanged' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.   C:\Users\raj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite13\Default.aspx   46  
Error   2   'ratingControl' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    C:\Users\raj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite13\Default.aspx.vb    16  48  WebSite13
Error   3   'ratingControl' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.    C:\Users\raj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite13\Default.aspx.vb    33  13  WebSite13
Error   4   'lbltxt' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.   C:\Users\raj\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\WebSite13\Default.aspx.vb    34  13  WebSite13
```

I have no idea which one is causing the error `My DB name is Test and Table name is ratings`

This is my default.aspx

```
<%@ Register Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" TagPrefix="ajax" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<script runat="server">

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    End Sub
</script>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title>Ajax Rating Sample</title>
<style type="text/css">
.ratingEmpty
{
background-image: url(ratingStarEmpty.gif);
width:18px;
height:18px;
}
.ratingFilled
{
background-image: url(ratingStarFilled.gif);
width:18px;
height:18px;
}
.ratingSaved
{
 background-image: url(ratingStarSaved.gif);
width:18px;
height:18px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<ajax:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScripManager1" runat="server"/>
<div>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="pnlRating" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
<table style="width:35%">
<tr>
<td style="width:20%">
<b>Average Rating:</b>
</td>
<td>
<ajax:Rating ID="ratingControl" AutoPostBack="true" OnChanged="RatingControlChanged" runat="server" StarCssClass="ratingEmpty" WaitingStarCssClass="ratingSaved" EmptyStarCssClass="ratingEmpty" FilledStarCssClass="ratingFilled">
</ajax:Rating>
<b> <asp:label ID="lbltxt" runat="server"/> </b>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2">
Testing
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is default.aspx.vb code

```
Imports System.Configuration
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

Partial Class _Default
    Inherits System.Web.UI.Page
    Private con As New SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("test").ConnectionString)
    Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
        If Not IsPostBack Then
            BindRatingControl()
        End If
    End Sub
    Protected Sub RatingControlChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs)
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("insert into rating(rate)values(@Rating)", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Rating", ratingControl.CurrentRating)
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close()
        BindRatingControl()
    End Sub
    Protected Sub BindRatingControl()
        Dim total As Integer = 0
        Dim dt As New DataTable()
        con.Open()
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("Select Rate from rating", con)
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
        da.Fill(dt)
        If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
            For i As Integer = 0 To dt.Rows.Count - 1
                total += Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows(i)(0).ToString())
            Next
            Dim average As Integer = total \ (dt.Rows.Count)
            ratingControl.CurrentRating = average
            lbltxt.Text = dt.Rows.Count & "user(s) have rated this article"
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

So can any Help me how to solve this issuse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your default.aspx page (front end) appears to be missing the needed page declaration - this is what tells it which codebehind to use.

It should be at the very top line of the default.aspx file.

An example default page declaration:

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="VB.net" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" 
AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebTest._Default" %>
```

The important pieces are:

```
CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" 
Inherits="WebTest._Default"
```

This tells the `ASP.net` engine which file and class name to associate with the page.

Are you sure you didn't accidentally erase that line and save the file?

This should be easy to restore, just copy from another file and fix the `CodeBehind` and `Inherits` (and `Title`) attributes to have the proper values.