# how to run a C# command with javascript ?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

take a look at this program:

WebForm1.aspx is supposed to call the C# command  Button1_Click  which is from MultiCust_MultipleFunction.cs , but when I run the code it gives an error for  MultiCust_MultipleFunction.cs. It says Button1 is not defined in the current context.

btw when i run the program i get  "an error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request global asax"

MultiCust_MultipleFunction.cs :

```
MultiCust_MultipleFunction.cs :

using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Collections;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;

public partial class MultiCust_MultipleFunction : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "ShowMessage()");
    }
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("Zaq");
    }
}
```

---

WebForm1.aspx:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head runat="server">
    <title>Execute Multiple function with a Button</title>
</head>


<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function ShowMessage() {
        alert("Hi");
    }


</script>


<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" OnClick="Button1_Click" Text="Button" /></div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is that your entire WebForm1.aspx file?

Comment: Where is your `<%@ page ... />` declaration? If it's missing then it's most likely your problem. Also looks like you might have detailed errors turned off in web.config and aren't seeing the true/actual error. See this question and my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/21517188/546000 - not 100% sure which is why I am posting as comment, not answer; hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

code looks okay, try delete the button, then add it again (make sure the debugger is not running), then click build under project, that should fix it.

Comment: okay, i have changed OnClick to OnClientClick, but it still giving the same error that Button1 is not defined.

Answer (score 0):

Call the method on the `OnClientClick`

```
Button1.Attributes.Add("OnClientClick", "ShowMessage();")
```

Hope this help